# jQuery keeps adding display: block to my table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var str = '<tr class="task_row"><td>data.name</td><td>data.description</td></tr>';
$(str)
    .hide()
    .insertAfter($(clicked_item)
                     .parent()
                     .parent()
                     .parent()
                     .next()
                     .find('.header_row')
                 )
    .fadeIn("slow");
```

For some reason, when jQuery shows the new row, it gives the `<tr>` a `display: block` style which makes the entire row only take up one cell. Is there any way to keep it from behaving this way?

Comment: can you give us an html output example of this: `$(clicked_item).parent().parent().parent().next().find('.header_row')`

Comment: for me it's working correct, ensure that `$(clicked_item).parent().parent().parent().next().find('.header_row')` will give you a `<tr>` back

Comment: It does ... and did your table have more than one column?  The display: block was forcing the new row to display in only the first column.  I also checked the dom with firebug, and it was putting the TR in the right spot but with the added "display: block"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

If I add:

```
$('.task_row').css('display', 'table-row');
```

after the animation line, it displays properly.

Answer (score 0):

After `.fadeIn()` jQuery automatically adds `display: block` to the element (for CSS priority I guess). You can remove it after `.fadeIn()` finishes it's job. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/mP3mP/):

```
var str = '<tr class="task_row"><td>data.name</td><td>data.description</td></tr>';
$(str)
    .hide()
    .insertAfter($(clicked_item)
                     .parent()
                     .parent()
                     .parent()
                     .next()
                     .find('.header_row')
                 )
    .fadeIn("slow", function() { $(this).removeAttr('style'); });
```